# automate SFTP process with different ssh version

Tags: ssh, sftp, rsa, authorized-keys

I am totally new to this. Please bear with me if my question is totally nuts. I am trying to setup rsa keys between two servers. I tried the following steps.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

copied the `id_rsa.pub` as `authorized_keys` in the remote servers `/.ssh/` folder

sftp is still asking for a password.

tried `sftp -e` also. and tried changing `authorized_keys` to `authorized_key2` in remote. Nothing is working

One thing that bothers me is `ssh -V` returns SSH protocols 1.5/2.0 in my server and SFTP version is SFTP protocol version 3 in the remote server. I am not sure whether this is the problem.

Can anyone please suggest? Really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Try to determine which protocol is actually used between ssh-client and ssh-server (e.g. removing the entry from host's `.ssh/known_hosts` and connecting again) - is RSA used at all? Maybe, ECDSA or DSA is used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply EarlGray. I removed the known_hosts and when i tried connecting i am able to see "DSA key fingerprint is....". Does this mean i have to use DSA?

Comment: i did try ssh-keygen -t dsa after that and try posting the id_dsa.pub as authorized_keys. Still not working. It still prompts for the password. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Does your id_rsa.pub look like this?:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCqGKukO1De7zhZj6+H0qtjTkVxwTCpvKe4eCZ0
FPqri0cb2JZfXJ/DgYSF6vUpwmJG8wVQZKjeGcjDOL5UlsuusFncCzWBQ7RKNUSesmQRMSGkVb1/
3j+skZ6UtW+5u09lHNsj6tQ51s1SPrCBkedbNf0Tp0GbMJDyR4e9T04ZZwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

If so then you're authorized_keys thing needs to look more like this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAAgQCqGKukO1De7zhZj6+H0qtjTkVxwTCpvKe4eCZ0FPqri0cb2JZfXJ/DgYSF6vUpwmJG8wVQZKjeGcjDOL5UlsuusFncCzWBQ7RKNUSesmQRMSGkVb1/3j+skZ6UtW+5u09lHNsj6tQ51s1SPrCBkedbNf0Tp0GbMJDyR4e9T04ZZw== phpseclib-generated-key
```

Also, fyi, the SFTP vs. SSH version really doesn't matter that much.  SFTP has versions 0 - 6.  SSH has 1-2.  SFTP (any version) only works on SSHv2.